# Need to move data from one cell to the adjoining cell in a different column

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, move

I have a spreadsheet where the data in the cells are not under the correct columns.  For example, the heading in Column H is "Houston", but I have data in cells B29, D11, K9 that should be in the Houston column.  Is there an easy If/Then formula that will look at each cell and move the data to the adjoining cell in the correct column?

If it is helpful the data in the cells match the column header.

[image: Example of table]

Comment: But your screenshot doesn't cover the mentioned range "but I have data in cells B29, D11, K9"

Comment: It was just an example...